# Field set as list item in sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I wanna create a fieldset as a list item in sencha touch 2 ie, when i click add button. a fieldset repeats itself with different entered values.How do I do this. I knw there is something called itemTpl.but I dont know how to call a fieldset inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DataItem approach if you want to add standard Sencha component to list because itemTpl doesn't support it. Here is an article explaining how : http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/